Ошибка с HTTPS в ASP.NET Core на Fedora
У меня есть проект ASP.NET Core (API) + React, который раньше локально запускался без ошибок, но недавно добавилась задача, я запускаю проект без изменений, а теперь есть ошибка.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Https.Internal.HttpsConnectionMiddleware[1] 
Failed to authenticate HTTPS connection. 
System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: Authentication failed, see inner exception. 
---> Interop+OpenSsl+SslException: SSL Handshake failed with OpenSSL error - SSL_ERROR_SSL. 
---> Interop+Crypto+OpenSslCryptographicException: error:0A000416:SSL routines::ssl/tls alert certificate unknown
dotnet dev-certs https выдаёт

A valid HTTPS certificate is already present

А dotnet dev-certs https --trust завершается с ошибкой

There was an error trusting the HTTPS developer certificate. It will be trusted by some clients but not by others.

Что с этим можно сделать ?
Код в Program.cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Json;
// more usings here

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Logging.ClearProviders();
builder.Logging.AddConsole();
builder.Host.ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
{
    config.AddJsonFile("somefile.json");
    // more files here
});

builder.Services.AddHttpLogging(options =>
{
    // options.LoggingFields = HttpLoggingFields.All;
    // options.LoggingFields = HttpLoggingFields.RequestPropertiesAndHeaders |
    //                         HttpLoggingFields.RequestBody;
});
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.Configure<JsonOptions>(options =>
{
    options.SerializerOptions.IncludeFields = true;
});
builder.Services.AddSingleton<ParseConfigService, ParseConfigService>();
builder.Services.AddHttpClient();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<GiftboxDbContext>(options =>
{
    //...
});
builder.Services
       .AddIdentityCore<IdentityUser>(options =>
       {
           options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false;
           // more options here
       })
       .AddEntityFrameworkStores<GiftboxDbContext>();

builder.Services
    .AddAuthentication()
    .AddScheme<AuthenticationSchemeOptions, ApiKeyAuthenticationHandler>(
        "ApiKey", options => {  }
    );

builder.Services.AddScoped<ApiKeyService>();
// more services here

var app = builder.Build();
app.UseHttpLogging();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");;

app.Run();



А какая у вас версия .NET? Попробуйте dotnet dev-certs https --clean, а затем уже dotnet dev-certs https --trust Можете ещё попробовать почитать https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56409580/trouble-trusting-local-https-certificate-in-asp-net-core и https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64017267/dotnet-dev-certs-certificate-not-trusted

@CrazyElf забыл дописать, .NET 6, но если сменить на .NET 8, то эта ошибка остаётся. К сожалению эти две команды тоже с ошибками завершаются.

Вот это ещё попробуйте почитать: https://serverfault.com/questions/639837/openssl-s-client-shows-alert-certificate-unknown-but-all-server-certificates-app Я не знаю ответа, это только читать все ссылки и разбираться. Сертификаты для меня лично сложная тема.
